# Async web calls bottlenecking and running sequencially

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, iis, asynchronous, web

I have a web site which makes frequent requests to an external web service, and I'd like these calls to be async and parallel to avoid blocking and to speed up the site a bit. Basically, I have 8 widgets, each of which has to make its own web call(s).

For some reason, only the first 3 or so of them truly load async, and then the threads don't free up in time, and the rest of the widgets load sequencially. If i could get 3 of them to load in parallel, then 3 more in parallel, then 2 more in parallel, i'd be happy. So the issue is really that the threads aren't freeing up in time.

I'm guessing the answer has to do with some IIS configuration. I'm testing on a non-server OS, so maybe that's part of it.

Edit for @jon skeet:

I'm using reflection to invoke the web calls like this:

```
output = methodInfo.Invoke(webservice, parameters);
```

The widget actions (which eventually call the web service) are called via a jquery $.each() loop and the .load function (maybe this causes a bottleneck?). The widget actions are set up as async methods in an async controller.

Here is the code for one of the async methods (they are all set up like this):

```
public void MarketTradeWidgetAsync()
    {
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();

        //a bunch of market trade logic


        //this eventually calls the web service
        PlanUISetting uiSettingMarketQuotesConfig = WebSettingsProviderManager.Provider.GetMarketQuotes(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Theme"], SessionValues<String>.GlobalPlanID, SessionValues<String>.ParticipantID, "MARKETQUOTES");

        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();

    }


public ActionResult MarketTradeWidgetCompleted(MarketTradeTool markettradetool)
    {
        if (Session.IsNewSession)
            return PartialView("../Error/AjaxSessionExpired");
        else
        {
            ViewData["MarketData"] = markettradetool;
            return PartialView(markettradetool);
        }
    }
```

And, like I said, these methods are called via jquery. My thinking is that since the action methods are async, they should give control back to the jquery after they get called, right?

Comment: Please show the code you're using to call the web service.

Comment: Edited to include a little bit about the workflow

Comment: That doesn't look particularly asynchronous to me. Again, more information would be really helpful...

Comment: oh and by the way, I read your article, "making reflection fly" a few weeks ago and learned a lot. I actually tried to replace that reflection with delegates, but ended up having to go back to reflection

Comment: well, I was hoping that since the widget action methods are async methods, the jquery would invoke all of them asynchronously. There isn't a whole lot more info I have to give, unfortunately. It appears as if it's working asynchronously to a certain point, and then it runs out of threads and never recycles them..

Comment: also, using miniprofiler, I find that it's hanging on the call to the action method (the .load() call)

Comment: Well you say they're async methods, but we really haven't got any context. We don't know what kind of web service this is, or what methods you're calling. Basically, we don't have a lot to go on.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10612/discussion-between-phillip-schmidt-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: Not really - partly because there are too many layers involved, and it's not clear what diagnostics you've performed to work out what's going on. I would try to take jQuery out of the picture by making the requests directly from a test app.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I wish I could give you context on the whole workflow here, but you're right-- there are quite a few layers here. Maybe I can just ask a more generic question in the place of my original: What do you think is the best way to implement this kind of behavior in a fairly high traffic MVC app? Basically, I have a widget page with 1-8 widgets, and I want them to load in the fastest way possible and without blocking the UI. The widgets each make the web calls -- which, by the way, are SOAP requests.

Comment: I wouldn't like to say, to be honest - that definitely sounds like a different question (determining the appropriate approach rather than diagnosing a bottleneck). It *may* be worth you deleting this question and writing a new one. (I probably wouldn't be able to help with that one, unfortunately.)

Comment: Well, one more addition.. using miniprofiler, I can see that the hold up is on the CALL to the action. It never even makes it into the action method code before it gets queued up. That is, the last code that has control  before one of the delays is the jquery. Does that narrow it down any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SessionState = "readonly" for the page at hand fixed this issue. Evidently session locking was the issue.